# Move line starting with specific_text_a below line starting with specific_text_b

Tags: macos, shell, sed

I am trying to move an existing line that starts with let's say: `abc::` below an existing line that starts with `id:` in various md files in a folder.

Let's assume the files looked like this

```
(file 1)
 text
 id: 123
 more text
 abc:: cba
```

```
(file 2)
 text
 id: 321
 more text
 a lot more text
 abc:: def
```

The result of running the code should in both cases be that `abc::...` moves right below `id:...`

My assumption was, that the following code, would move the line that starts with `abc::` right below the line that contains `id:`
However, if I run the code, it runs over the files (as per edited timestamp), but changes nothing.

MWE:

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec sed -i '' '/^id:/{
N
s/\n\(abc::.*\)/\1\
/
}' {} +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed`command (executed via `find`'s `-exec`) should do the trick:

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec sed -i '' '
/^id:/,/^abc::/{
    /^id:/b
    /^abc::/{p; x; s/.//p; d;}
    ${x; s/.//p; x; p; d;}
    H; d
}' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk, including the default BSD one on MacOS:

```
$ head *.md
==> file1.md <==
text
id: 123
more text
abc:: cba

==> file2.md <==
text
id: 321
more text
a lot more text
abc:: def
```

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.md' -exec awk '
    FNR == 1 { prt() }
    { all[++n] = $0 }
    /^abc::/ { src = n }
    /^id:/   { dst = n }
    END { prt() }

    function prt(    i) {
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            if ( (i != src) || (dst == 0) ) {
                print all[i] > fname
            }
            if ( (i == dst) && (src != 0) ) {
                print all[src] > fname
            }
        }
        close(fname)
        fname = FILENAME
        src = dst = n = 0
    }
' {} +
```

```
$ head *.md
==> file1.md <==
text
id: 123
abc:: cba
more text

==> file2.md <==
text
id: 321
abc:: def
more text
a lot more text
```

That would work even if the `abc::` line came before the `id:` line in the input and if one or the other didn't appear in the input it'd just print the file as-is.

Comment: thank you! it does work insofar as it is putting abc:: below id: however, it does print both to the very bottom of the file instead of moving the abc:: part right below the existing id. (I went with your exact code sample)

Comment: No, it does exactly what you asked for as shown in my answer. If that's not what you're seeing then you did something wrong when copy/pasting my script.